# Why do Thunderbird emails to a particular type of addresses consistently bounce?

Tags: thunderbird, email

Emails I send to people with gmx.de in the second part of their address consistently bounce, while these people don't seem to have a problem on their side: they happily send me mail and receive it from others on this address. The problem does not seem to be in my undesired mail detection (which is only for incoming mail anyway, isn't it? I'm still training it, I've only been on Thunderbird for a month now). When I still used Windows Outlook (until recently) I did not have this problem. Very happy if anybody has a suggestion!

Comment: Without any kind of bounce messages to analyze, logs etc. it's rather hard to tell anything.

Comment: "(which is only for incoming mail anyway, isn't it? " yes. You really need to look at the contents of the message you get from the bounce.

Comment: Here's the usual bounce message: This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification.

Delivery to the following recipients failed.

     .......@gmx.net





Reporting-MTA: dns;cpsmtpb-ews05.kpnxchange.com
Received-From-MTA: dns;cpsps-ews27.kpnxchange.com
Arrival-Date: Wed, 26 Oct 2016 10:33:24 +0200

Final-Recipient: rfc822;l.wirl@gmx.net
Action: failed
Status: 5.6.1
Diagnostic-Code: smtp;554 5.6.1 Body type not supported by Remote Host

Comment: So it's gmx.net, not gmx.de, sorry.

Comment: PS My OS is freshbook, which is a Xubuntu adaptation. (http://www.freshbook.nl/)

Answer (score 0):

In Thunderbird open the *Tools* menu and then go to *Options* -> *Advanced* -> *General* -> *Advanced Configuration* -> *Config Editor*. Confirm the warning that you will be careful and then press the keyboard combination Ctrl + F. This opens a search window. Fill in the window: `mail.strictly_mime`. Press Enter, and you come out with that preference. Adjust it to `true`.<sup>[Source](https://forum.kpn.com/e-mail-10/mail-body-type-not-supported-by-remote-host-416034)</sup>